# Send Text to an inputbox using win32 api

Tags: winapi, sendmessage

I'm trying to send some text to an inputput box using win32. Some text appears in the inputbox, but it is all jumbled (?????????a??????).

The code is :

SendMessage(myHandle, WM_SETTEXT, 1, "A")

Comment: Is the input box in the same process?  Is it a standard Win32 input box?  Is it expecting unicode?

Comment: Yes, Yes (I belive the input part is technically an edit) and I'm not sure. Examples I have seen, just use plain text.

Comment: Here is the msdn article :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775462%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Are you building your application as UNICODE or ANSI?  Usually you will see question marks like that if the control is expecting a unicode string, but you are sending ANSI.

Comment: The inputbox is not created from my application, it is created externally (say from a vbscript file). I don't know what encoding it should take, it appears to be a standard edit control.
My application is written in VB.NET. I tried changing the encoding to :

 SendMessage(myHandle, WM_SETTEXT, 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("A").toString)

Same results. Is that what you were suggesting?

Comment: and :

SendMessage(myHandle, WM_SETTEXT, 0, Encoding.unicode.GetBytes("A").toString)

Comment: Use IsWindowUnicode() to find out whether a window expects Ansi or Unicode text messages.

Comment: @Remy, that's incorrect: for the standard messages (<WM_USER), Windows translates unicode/ansi as appropriate for the target window, so what matters is how your code is compiled (or rather, which version of SendMessage A vs W you are calling), not the unicode/ansi type of the target. So if your app is compiled as ANSI, SendMessage will actually be be SendMessageA so should get an ANSI string (and USER32 will translate appropriately before delivering to the target); but if you've compiled as UNICODE, then SendMessage is SendMessageW and expects a Unicode string.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is the root cause, but as long as the target window (edit box in your case) is in the same process, you should call SetWindowText() rather than sending WM_TEXT directly.

HTH,

Comment: +1 to this; SetWindowText takes a typed string as a param (rather than the generic LPARAM of SendMessage), so makes it near impossible to get Unicode/Ansi string mixed up. If you accidentally pass the wrong type, you'll get a helpful compiler error. (...and if you do get such an error, fix it by using the appropriate string type, not by 'casting it away', which is a common rookie mistake.)

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this as mentioned below:-

```
SendMessage(myHandle,WM_SETTEXT,NULL,(LPARAM)L"A");
```

Comment: This is the right answer *assuming* that the app is compiled with UNICODE defined.